# How to save RichTextBox content to image

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, richtextbox

I need to save the content of the RichTextBox on image and be able to place it in one of the corners.

I tried to do this in several ways. First I put the contents of the RichTextBox into XML and then measuring and drawing the individual strings using TextRenderer. Unfortunately, when using different font sizes and FontFamily it proved very painful to align the text correctly.

I wondered if I can somehow save the content of RichTexBox into the image, clipped to the size of the text. Set a transparent background and then place it on a target image?

I do not care whether the solution will involve a RichTextBox in WPF or Windows Forms.

Thanks for advice

Comment: You can print the content of your `RichTextBox` by sending a `EM_FORMATRANGE` message to it. You can draw the content in graphics object that belongs to an image. You may find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32401415/3110834) helpful.

Comment: Maybe the question is a duplicate for WPF but is there any suitable answer for windows forms? If there is, its good to share an answer also for winforms.