# Print richTextBox content in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have to print on my printer the content of a richTextBox called richTextBox1.
I have a "pictureBox1" that i use as button.
I found a code that i use but i print an empty pages.
This is the code that i use:

```
private void printDocument1_BeginPrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
        {
            char[] param = { '\n' };

            if (printDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrintRange == PrintRange.Selection)
            {
                lines = richTextBox1.SelectedText.Split(param);
            }
            else
            {
                lines = richTextBox1.Text.Split(param);
            }

            int i = 0;
            char[] trimParam = { '\r' };
            foreach (string s in lines)
            {
                lines[i++] = s.TrimEnd(trimParam);
            }
        }

        private int linesPrinted;
        private string[] lines;

        private void OnPrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            int x = e.MarginBounds.Left;
            int y = e.MarginBounds.Top;
            Brush brush = new SolidBrush(richTextBox1.ForeColor);

            while (linesPrinted < lines.Length)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(lines[linesPrinted++],
                    richTextBox1.Font, brush, x, y);
                y += 15;
                if (y >= e.MarginBounds.Bottom)
                {
                    e.HasMorePages = true;
                    return;
                }
            }

            linesPrinted = 0;
            e.HasMorePages = false;
        }
        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Stampa dello scontrino

            if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                printDocument1.Print();
            }
        }

        private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            this.printDocument1.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(this.OnPrintPage);
        }
```

Can someone help me?

I'd like to print all the content of richTextBox without ank me confirm to use a specific printer (use the default printer).

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32386527/printing-richtextbox